# Distance Dependence of Weak Forces

Tags: intermolecular-forces

I am currently taking a Biochemistry course and one of the topics on midterm covers various weak forces and its distance dependence. We covered:

- charge-charge (ionic)
- hydrogen bonds
- van der waals
- hydrophobic effect

I am not sure how to put them in order and how they interact with each other once distance comes into play.
If anyone can explain in details, it would be very helpful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does "the book cover various weak forces and its (sic) distance dependence" or not?

Comment: If you look up 'intermolecular  forces' on Wikipedia you will find answers to your question.